# XSLT 2.0, templates and matching

Tags: xml, xslt

XSLT newbie (thanks in advance)

I have an XML file containing payment data. I am trying to transform it into an xml format used by a bank. The XML needs to be different based on the payment type (urgent payment/wire, standard payment/ETF or manual payment). Multiple payments are possible in a given file. Here is a sample of the source XML (simplified, two transactions, both the same payment type)

```
<Payments>
 <Payment xmlns:ns="urn:com.bank/paymentconnector">
  <Payment_Detail>
   <Payment_Info>
    <ns:PAYMENT_Payment_Memo>Payment Info1</ns:PAYMENT_Payment_Memo>
    <ns:PAYMENT_Payment_Amount>1111</ns:PAYMENT_Payment_Amount>
    <ns:PAYMENT_Type>Wire</ns:PAYMENT_Type>
    <ns:PAYMENT_Currency_Code>USD</ns:PAYMENT_Currency_Code>
    <ns:PAYMENT_Check_or_Advice_Number>0</ns:PAYMENT_Check_or_Advice_Number>
  </Payment_Info>
 <Payer_Data>
    <ns:PAYER_Company_Name>Company, LLP</ns:PAYER_Company_Name>
    <ns:PAYER_Address_Line_1>Main st</ns:PAYER_Address_Line_1>
    <ns:PAYER_Address_Line_2>Line 2</ns:PAYER_Address_Line_2>
    <ns:PAYER_City>Cleveland</ns:PAYER_City>
    <ns:PAYER_Zip_Code>11111</ns:PAYER_Zip_Code>
    <ns:PAYER_Country>US</ns:PAYER_Country>
    <ns:PAYER_Account_Number>1111-11111111</ns:PAYER_Account_Number>
    <ns:PAYER_Currency>USD</ns:PAYER_Currency>
 </Payer_Data>
 <Payee_Data>
    <ns:PAYEE_Name>Name</ns:PAYEE_Name>
    <ns:PAYEE_Bank_Name>Bank Name</ns:PAYEE_Bank_Name>
    <ns:PAYEE_Bank_Account_Name>Account Name</ns:PAYEE_Bank_Account_Name>
    <ns:PAYEE_Account_Number>1111111</ns:PAYEE_Account_Number>
    <ns:PAYEE_Masked_Account_Number>********** </ns:PAYEE_Masked_Account_Number>
    <ns:PAYEE_Account_Type>DD</ns:PAYEE_Account_Type>
    <ns:PAYEE_Routing_Transit_Number>22222</ns:PAYEE_Routing_Transit_Number>
    <ns:PAYEE_Bank_Country>US</ns:PAYEE_Bank_Country>
    </Payee_Data>
   </Payment_Detail>
  </Payment>
<Payment>
  <Payment_Detail>
   <Payment_Info>
    <ns:PAYMENT_Payment_Memo>Payment Info2</ns:PAYMENT_Payment_Memo>
    <ns:PAYMENT_Payment_Amount>22222</ns:PAYMENT_Payment_Amount>
    <ns:PAYMENT_Type>Wire</ns:PAYMENT_Type>
    <ns:PAYMENT_Currency_Code>USD</ns:PAYMENT_Currency_Code>
    <ns:PAYMENT_Check_or_Advice_Number>0</ns:PAYMENT_Check_or_Advice_Number>
 </Payment_Info>
 <Payer_Data>
    <ns:PAYER_Company_Name>Company, LLP</ns:PAYER_Company_Name>
    <ns:PAYER_Address_Line_1>Main st</ns:PAYER_Address_Line_1>
    <ns:PAYER_Address_Line_2>Line 2</ns:PAYER_Address_Line_2>
    <ns:PAYER_City>Cleveland</ns:PAYER_City>
    <ns:PAYER_Zip_Code>11111</ns:PAYER_Zip_Code>
    <ns:PAYER_Country>US</ns:PAYER_Country>
    <ns:PAYER_Account_Number>1111-11111111</ns:PAYER_Account_Number>
    <ns:PAYER_Currency>USD</ns:PAYER_Currency>
 </Payer_Data>
 <Payee_Data>
    <ns:PAYEE_Name>Name</ns:PAYEE_Name>
    <ns:PAYEE_Bank_Name>Bank Name</ns:PAYEE_Bank_Name>
    <ns:PAYEE_Bank_Account_Name>Account Name</ns:PAYEE_Bank_Account_Name>
    <ns:PAYEE_Account_Number>1111111</ns:PAYEE_Account_Number>
    <ns:PAYEE_Masked_Account_Number>**********</ns:PAYEE_Masked_Account_Number>
    <ns:PAYEE_Account_Type>DD</ns:PAYEE_Account_Type>
    <ns:PAYEE_Routing_Transit_Number>22222</ns:PAYEE_Routing_Transit_Number>
    <ns:PAYEE_Bank_Country>US</ns:PAYEE_Bank_Country>
 </Payee_Data>
</Payment_Detail>
</Payments>
```

Here is my (simplified) output

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <!-- urgent payment-->
   <urgent_payment_header>
    <header_fields/>
    </urgent_payment_header>
    <paymentrec>
     <recordType>5</recordType>
     <payerAccNum>1111-11111111</payerAccNum>
     <!-- (other fields)-->
    </paymentrec>
    <paymentrec>
     <recordType>5</recordType>
    <payerAccNum></payerAccNum>
    <!-- continue with any other urgent payments in the file-->
   </paymentrec>
   <urgent_control_fields>
   </urgent_control_fields>

   <!-- standard payment-->
  <standard_payment_header>
  <header_fields/>
  </standard_payment_header>
  <paymentrec>
   <recordType>4</recordType>
   <payerAccNum>1111-11111111</payerAccNum>
    <!-- (other fields)-->
   </paymentrec>
   <paymentrec>
   <recordType>4</recordType>
   <payerAccNum></payerAccNum>
    <!-- continue with any other standard payments in the file-->
   </paymentrec>
   <standard_control_fields>
   </standard_control_fields>

  <!-- catch all payments-->
  <catchall_payment_header>
  <header_fields/>
  </catchall_payment_header>
  <paymentrec>
  <recordType>3</recordType>
  <payerAccNum>1111-11111111</payerAccNum>
<!-- (other fields)-->
   </paymentrec>
   <paymentrec>
   <recordType>3</recordType>
   <payerAccNum></payerAccNum>
    <!-- continue with any other catchall payments in the file-->
   </paymentrec>
   <catchall_control_fields>
   </catchall_control_fields>
```

my XSLT works when all of the payments in the source file are the same type (all urgent, all standard, all other types) with one header, the payment records listed out and then one control record

however, when the payment types are mixed (for example, one urgent and one standard) then only the header, first node and control record is written to the output. If a file contains an urgent payment/wire and a standard payment, I want the output to be

here is my (simplified XSLT)

```
 <!-- Begin writing the output-->
  <xsl:template match="Payments">
  <xsl:choose>
       <xsl:when test="Payment/Payment_Detail/Payment_Info[ns:PAYMENT_Type != 'Wire']">
                <xsl:call-template select="Payment-Header"/>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="Payment"/>
                <xsl:call-templates select="Payment-Control-Standard"/>
      </xsl:when>
       <xsl:when test="Payment/Payment_Detail/Payment_Info[ns:PAYMENT_Type = 'Wire']">
                 <xsl:call-template select="Payment-Header"/>
                 <xsl:apply-templates select="Payment"/> 
                 <xsl:call-template name="Payment-Control-Urgent"/>
       </xsl:when>
       <xsl:otherwise>
                 <xsl:call-template name="Payment-Header"/>
                 <xsl:apply-templates select="Payment"/> 
                 <xsl:call-template name="Payment-Control-CatchAll"/>
       </xsl:otherwise>
   </xsl:choose> 
  </xsl:template>


<xsl:template match="Payment">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="Payment_Detail/Payment_Info[ns:PAYMENT_Type != 'Wire']">
                <xsl:call-template name="Payment-Standard"/>  
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="Payment_Detail/Payment_Info[ns:PAYMENT_Type = 'Wire']">
                <xsl:call-template name="Payment-Urgent"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:call-template name="Payment-CatchAll"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

<!-- End writing the output-->

<!-- Begin template details-->

    <xsl:template name="Payment-Header">
        <header>
            (header fields, details not important)
        </header>
    </xsl:template>


<xsl:template name="Payment-Control-Standard">
    <control>
        <numberOfPayments>count of standard payments in the file</numberOfPayments>
        <sumOfPayments>sum of standard payments in the file</sumOfPayments>
    </control>  
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="Payment-Control-Urgent">
    <control>
        <numberOfPayments>count of urgent payments in the file</numberOfPayments>
        <sumOfPayments>sum of urgent payments in the file</sumOfPayments>
    </control>  
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="Payment-Control-CatchAll">
    <control>
        <numberOfPayments>count of catch all payments in the file</numberOfPayments>
        <sumOfPayments>sum of catch all payments in the file</sumOfPayments>
    </control>  
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="Payment-Standard">
 <paymentrec>
        (payment fields, details not important)
 </paymentrec>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="Payment-Urgent">
  <paymentrec>
        (payment fields, details not important)           
  </paymentrec>
 </xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="Payment-CatchAll">
  <paymentrec>
        (payment fields, details not important)           
  </paymentrec>
 </xsl:template>
```

Comment: Code like `<xsl:when test="Payment/Payment_Detail/Payment_Info/ns:PAYMENT_Type != 'Wire']">` will simply give an XSLT or XPath syntax error about that unmatched closing square bracket `]`.

Comment: There are also numerous errors in the source XML. ns: is not defined, PAYMENT_Type is closed by PAYMENT_Currency in many locations, you have a closing tag wpc:PAYEE_Bank_Country for opening tag ns:PAYEE_Bank_Country. Take the time to first post a valid XML before asking us to attempt to fix the issues as we would need to fix all these errors first.

Comment: Sorry. I was chopping up the actual source xml/xslt to try and make it easier to understand and made the problem worse. (Edited)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing with

```
<xsl:template match="Payments">
  <xsl:choose>
       <xsl:when test="Payment/Payment_Detail/Payment_Info/ns:PAYMENT_Type != 'Wire']">
```

is that it evaluates to true if there is at least **one** `Payment` element with `PAYMENT_Type` not 'Wire'. This is probably not, what you want.

If one record in the input is to be transformed into one record in the output and nothing else is to be done, then you don't need a general template für `Payments`. So, I'd suggest to completly delete the template for `Payments` and do the important stuff inside the `Payment` template.

Inside your current template for `Payment` I can see two problems:

- As  Martin Honnen already pointet out, you have a syntax error there: `]`is superfluous.
- By calling the template via xsl:apply-templates your context node is already `Payment`, so `Payment` in the XPath expressions is wrong.

Comment: I fixed the source xml/xslt

Comment: There can be 1 payment, or multiple payments.  right now if they are all the same payment type, everything works fine. it's if there are multiple payments but different types that's the problem

Comment: I got that. And I think, this is because of the structure of your XSLT. In your template for `Payments` you test first if there is anywere in the source a `Payment` with a `ns:PAYMENT_Type` not being 'Wire'. If yes, the templates inside the first `xsl:when` are called and nothing else is done. I.e. in this case, the instructions inside the other `xsl:when` and `xsl:otherwise` will never be executed. This is a design error of your XSLT. Again, I would suggest doing everything inside the `Payment` template.

Comment: If I do everything inside Payment, then I will have multiple headers/control sections. Or should I have different logic to handle that?

Comment: I didn't get thil now, that `control` and `header` are common for all records. (Sorry, your sample output it still no well-formed XML, therefore it's difficult to assess what you try to do). So you want to have one `control` for every 'Urgent' payment record, one `control` for every 'Standard Payment' etc? In this case, I'd suggest using `xsl:for-each-group` inside a `Payments` template.

Comment: Thanks! I updated the output to be well formed to help. I will also try the for-each-group. I have used for-each & for-each-group in the past and I'm trying to use templates where I can to stop thinking in a procedural language in xslt.

Comment: The headers/controls aren't common. they are different for each type (urgent, standard, everything else). The problem I'm having whether through templates or for-each-group is I  have to check to see what kind of payment, write the header, write the transaction, write the control.  if I have more than one type of payment in my source, then it stops after only the first transaction due to the test condition

Comment: In order to keep things clean, I put my new suggestion in a new answer. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

While, I'm still not 100% sure I get what you want, I'll give it another try.

I've simplified your input XML a little bit while adding another case for the Payment Method. It looks now like this:

```
<Payments xmlns:ns="urn:com.bank/paymentconnector">
    <Payment>
        <Payment_Detail>
            <Payment_Info>
                <ns:PAYMENT_Type>Wire</ns:PAYMENT_Type>
            </Payment_Info>
            <Payer_Data>
                <ns:PAYER_Company_Name>Company1</ns:PAYER_Company_Name>
            </Payer_Data>
        </Payment_Detail>
    </Payment>

    <Payment>
        <Payment_Detail>
            <Payment_Info>
                <ns:PAYMENT_Type>Wire</ns:PAYMENT_Type>
            </Payment_Info>
            <Payer_Data>
                <ns:PAYER_Company_Name>Company2</ns:PAYER_Company_Name>
            </Payer_Data>
        </Payment_Detail>
    </Payment>

    <Payment>
        <Payment_Detail>
            <Payment_Info>
                <ns:PAYMENT_Type>Something else than Wire</ns:PAYMENT_Type>
            </Payment_Info>
            <Payer_Data>
                <ns:PAYER_Company_Name>Company3</ns:PAYER_Company_Name>
            </Payer_Data>
        </Payment_Detail>
    </Payment>

    <Payment>
        <Payment_Detail>
            <Payment_Info>
                <ns:PAYMENT_Type>Something else than Wire</ns:PAYMENT_Type>
            </Payment_Info>
            <Payer_Data>
                <ns:PAYER_Company_Name>Company4</ns:PAYER_Company_Name>
            </Payer_Data>
        </Payment_Detail>
    </Payment>   
</Payments>
```

Now, if I get you right, you want a header for each distinct method of payment and some details for each record below. I'd suggest doing this in a for-each-group like so:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
 xmlns:ns="urn:com.bank/paymentconnector"
 version="2.0">
     <xsl:template match="/">
      <any_root_element>
          <xsl:for-each-group select="//Payment" group-by="Payment_Detail/Payment_Info/ns:PAYMENT_Type">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="current-grouping-key() = 'Wire'">
                    <header_for_wire/>
                    <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
                        <paymentrec>
                        <details>
                        Paid by <xsl:value-of select="Payment_Detail/Payer_Data/ns:PAYER_Company_Name"/>
                        </details>
                        </paymentrec>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </xsl:when>

                <xsl:when test="current-grouping-key() = 'Something else than Wire'">
                    <header_for_something_else_than_wire/>
                    <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
                    <paymentrec>
                        <details>
                        Paid by <xsl:value-of select="Payment_Detail/Payer_Data/ns:PAYER_Company_Name"/>
                        </details>
                    </paymentrec>    
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </xsl:when>
            </xsl:choose>

        </xsl:for-each-group>

      </any_root_element>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

Which will result in this XML:

```
<any_root_element>
    <header_for_wire/>
    <paymentrec>
        <details> Paid by Company1</details>
    </paymentrec>
    <paymentrec>
        <details> Paid by Company2</details>
    </paymentrec>
    <header_for_something_else_than_wire/>
    <paymentrec>
        <details> Paid by Company3</details>
    </paymentrec>
    <paymentrec>
        <details> Paid by Company4</details>
    </paymentrec>
</any_root_element>
```

Is this more or less what you want? (Of course, if the details are common, you might want to build a template for it, in order to avoid repetition.)